# Publish Fails when referencing project Asp.Net 5

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, project.json

**I building a website with Asp.Net 5 - beta7**.  This project uses **several project dependencies** which I have written.  **Locally I can build and run** fine by using the "References -> Add Reference -> Solution Items" to add the project references.  However, when I publish to Azure Websites I get 500 internal server errors.

**Through troubleshooting**, I have found that if I add the projects as nuget packages I can deploy fine.  This however requires me to publish a nuget package to our company repo every time I want to make a change.

I have also gotten this to work by adding the project reference and **moving the references from the "dependencies" node in project.json to the "frameworks:dnx451:dependencies" node of project.json.**  eg:
`{ "dependencies" : {"project1" : "0.0.1-*"} }` becomes `{ "frameworks":{ "dnx451":{ "dependencies" : {"project1" : "0.0.1-*"}}}}`

So, what is the difference between dependencies in the frameworks node and top level dependencies? I know that frameworkAssemblies is for the GAC, but what is the difference for two?

Which should I be using? And what is recommended?

Comment: Is the assembly you're referencing a PCL assembly and what's in the "frameworks" node in your project.json?

Comment: Can you please share the project.json file?

Comment: Are your project dependencies all in the same solution? As mentioned, seeing the project.json would be helpful, *as well as* the global.json. Also, how are you publishing to Azure? Via Visual Studio or some other command (e.g. msdeploy)?

Comment: The assemblies are all new Class Library (Package) which I believe is called "ASP.NET Class Library" (forgive my ignorance). 

The class library projects have their own sln, but I have added the projects to the src directory of my web sln.  

The project.json/global.json for the web project are located [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/seve2CqHyexqJ3ABb2Bw)

I am publishing to windows Azure via Visual Studio